# Template function which returns its INDEX'th parameter

Tags: c++

How can I create a template function, which returns its INDEX'th parameter?

```
template <int INDEX, typename ...PARAMETERS>
auto &&select(PARAMETERS&& ...parameters);
```

I know a "heavyweight" solution:

```
template <int INDEX, typename ...PARAMETERS>
auto &&select(PARAMETERS&& ...parameters) {
    std::tuple<PARAMETERS&&...> t(parameters...);
    return std::get<INDEX>(t);
}
```

I don't really like this solution, as it depends heavily on the compiler optimizer. Besides, it could slow down debug builds because of the unnecessary tuples.

Or I know a not-very scalable (but performance-OK) solution:

```
template <int INDEX>
struct SelectNthParameter;

template <>
struct SelectNthParameter<0> {
    template <typename PAR0, typename ...TAIL>
    static PAR0 &&value(PAR0 &&par0, TAIL&& ...tail) {
        return forward<PAR0>(par0);
    }
};

template <>
struct SelectNthParameter<1> {
    template <typename PAR0, typename PAR1, typename ...TAIL>
    static PAR1 &&value(PAR0 &&par0, PAR1 &&par1, TAIL&& ...tail) {
        return forward<PAR1>(par1);
    }
};
// add more template specializations for 2...inf
```

Is there any better (more lightweight, scalable) solution for this problem?

Comment: You probably want a recursive template - a special case for `<0>`, and the general case that invokes itself with `INDEX-1`. That's how `std::get` is implemented. In the end, I suspect it'll produce the exact same code as your "heavyweight" approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, nothing earth shattering:

```
template <int INDEX>
struct SelectNthParameter {
    template <typename HEAD, typename ...TAIL>
    __attribute__((always_inline))
    static auto &&value(HEAD &&head, TAIL &&...tail) {
        return SelectNthParameter<INDEX-1>::value(tail...);
    }
};

template <>
struct SelectNthParameter<0> {
    template <typename HEAD, typename ...TAIL>
    __attribute__((always_inline))
    static auto &&value(HEAD &&head, TAIL &&...) {
        return std::forward<HEAD>(head);
    }
};
```

Because of always_inline, this solution is more efficient than `tuple` (in debug builds, only 2 asm instructions are generated for each parameter, much more less than the `tuple` version).

And I can be more sure that this will be optimized away in release builds. I'm not 100% satisfied with this solution either, but this is better than the examples in the question.